# Nested else if in javascript

Tags: javascript

In this random number guessing, after obtaining input from user, if its is wrong (it should go to else) it does not go to the else statement. I can't find where it went wrong.

```
 var guess = prompt("Enter A Value Guessing Between 1 to 10 !");
 guessint = parseInt(guess);
 var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1;

 if (guessint === random) {
     document.write("Guessed Correct");
 } else if (guessint > random) {
     var guessgreat = prompt("Try again with value LESSER than " + guessint);

     if (parseInt(guessgreat) === random) {
         document.write("Guessed Correct great");
     }
 } else if (guessint < random) {
     var guessless = prompt("Try again with value GREATER than " + guessint);

     if (parseInt(guessless) === random) {
         document.write("Guessed Correct Less");
     }
 } else {
     document.write("Oops Guessed wrong");
 }
```

Comment: What is the condition it should go to else statement, from first view you covered all conditions with else if statements.

Comment: if my guessless or guessgreat not equal to random it should go to else

Comment: How should it work? The else you want to trigger belongs to an outside block. You have to redesign the application.

Comment: @JeffRSon where do i add else inside? i tried to add it in still it wouldn't work

Comment: Seems more like you should loop until you've guessed, as-is you get only two guesses, and don't check all conditions after the second. Take a step back, get a pen and paper and play computer for a little bit-it will help you reason about what is, and what should be, happening.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that both `guessint` and `random` are indeed defined numbers, then your `else` condition will never be reached, because when comparing one number against another the only three logical outcomes are that the first is equal, less to, or greater than, the second.

Comment: can you explain it i didn't get it?

Comment: The program will never reach the `else` code because it can never happen.

Answer (score 0):

You have obscure `{` in last `else if` statement, i've hightlighted it with `___^___` in code snippet below, remove it and everything suppose to work as expected:

```
else if(guessint<random)
{
  var guessless = prompt("Try Again With Valur GREATER than "+guessint)          
  if(parseInt(guessless)===random)
  {

      document.write("Guessed Correct Less")
   }

   }
___^___
 else
    {
   document.write("Oops Guessed wrong");
    }
```

Comment: I tried what you have suggested still didn't work for me ! did it work for you

Answer (score 0):

Updated code, you need to have the else inside, updated code below.

```
var guess = prompt("Enter A Value Guessing Between 1 to 10 !");
guessint = parseInt(guess);
console.log(guessint);
var random = 4; //Math.floor(Math.random()*10)+1;
console.log(random);
if (guessint === random) {
document.write("Guessed Correct");
} else if (guessint > random) {
var guessgreat = prompt("Try Again with value LESSER than " + guessint);
if (parseInt(guessgreat) === random) {
    document.write("Guessed Correct great");
}else {
document.write("Oops Guessed wrong");
}
} else if (guessint < random) {
var guessless = prompt("Try Again With Valur GREATER than " + guessint);
if (parseInt(guessless) === random) {
    document.write("Guessed Correct Less");
}else {
document.write("Oops Guessed wrong");
}
}
```

Comment: but i don't need 'else'' in every else if

Comment: In that case, the block wont get executed. 
Consider first condition
`guessint === random => 4===4 => "Guessed Correct"`
Second Condition
`guessint > random => 7 > 4 = > Try Again with value LESSER than 7`
`parseInt(guessgreat) === random => 3 === 4 ` - Here it wont come out and look up for else. Since you have if inside of else if.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `while` loop for guessing. Stay in the loop while the input value is not equal to the random value.

Inside the loop, you need to check for greater, then and prompt the user. after promting, you need to convert the value to an integer with base 10.

If the value is smaller (the else part) prompt for a new number.

If the loop id leaved, you know the guessed value is found and display the message.

```js
var guess = prompt("Enter A Value Guessing Between 1 to 10 !"),
    guessint = parseInt(guess, 10),
    random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1;

while (guessint !== random) {
    if (guessint > random) {
        guessint = parseInt(prompt("Try Again with value LESSER than " + guessint), 10);
    } else {
        guessint = parseInt(prompt("Try Again With Valur GREATER than " + guessint), 10);
    }
}
document.write("Guessed Correct");
```

Comment: on executing this while loop above you give chance till they guess it correct but i wanna give them a chance if it's correct print "correct" else wrong and i am learning so i wanna do this with nested else if

Comment: in this case, you could use a counter and check if the number of tries is reached.

Answer (score 0):

Let's go through it step by step.

Let's say `random` is `10` and the user picks `9` (so `guessint = 9`).

Now let's replace those values on your `if` / `else` statements:

```
if (9 === 10) {  // False!

} else if (9 > 10) {  // False!

} else if (9 < 10) {  // True!

    /* Runs this part of the code */

} else {  // It will never get to this else!

}
```

No matter what value the user selects, it will *have* to be either:

- Equal to 10
- Greater than 10
- Lesser than 10

There is no number that will *not* match any of those conditions. So it will *always* enter one of your `if` statements, and never the last `else`.

You would need an `else` on every `if`, like [Thennarasan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38501987/4824627) said, or a control variable, like so:

```
var guessint = parseInt(prompt("Guess a value between 1 and 10!"));
var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1;

// Control variable
var guessed_correctly = false;

if (guessint === random) {
    // Correct on first chance
    guessed_correctly = true;
} else if (guessint > random) {
    // Second chance
    var guessgreat = prompt("Try again with a value LESSER than " + guessint);

    if (parseInt(guessgreat) === random) {
        // Correct on second chance
        guessed_correctly = true;
    } else {
        // Incorrect on second chance
        guessed_correctly = false;
    }
} else if (guessint < random) {
    // Second chance
    var guessless = prompt("Try again with a value GREATER than " + guessint);

    if (parseInt(guessless) === random) {
        // Correct on second chance
        guessed_correctly = true;
    } else {
        // Incorrect on second chance
        guessed_correctly = false;
    }
}

if (guessed_correctly === true) {
    // If the user was correct on any chance
    document.write("Congratulations!");
} else {
    // If the user was incorrect on both chances
    document.write("Oops! Guessed wrong!");
}
```

Alternatively, there are other methods to implement the game you're making with `while`s and such, but the example I've given is based on your format.